# Receiving 'Expiration Date is invalid' when processing credit card by Authorize.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, credit-card, authorize.net, financial

I'm posting to the auth.net web service to create a credit card transaction. In both test and live, if i use a 9 or below month, I get the error. It was working a while back but started getting this issue. I am left padding zeros to the month. So, the format I'm sending is YYYY-MM, per the specs. The card I'm using now has a 7/12 date and I've confirmed the value I'm sending is 2012-07. I still get this error.

I've seen [this](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Issues-in-both-liveMode-and-oldLiveMode/m-p/19232) post and am following what it said.
Any idea on what I'm missing?

Bill

Comment: I would examine the request by putting a breakpoint at the point where you are doing the web service call. Make sure that there's not something converting your 07 back to a 7. This might happen if you're trying to pass an integer instead of a string. Are you at any point in your code converting the expiration values to any non-string types?

Comment: I think you're on to something. I just found where it's converted to an int. Testing....

Comment: Just ran it. You're right. Converted to an int and that caused the problem.  Can't believe i missed it. If you want, post the answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: okay I've posted it. glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would examine the request by putting a breakpoint at the point where you are doing the web service call. Make sure that there's not something converting your 07 back to a 7. This might happen if you're trying to pass an integer instead of a string. Are you at any point in your code converting the expiration values to any non-string types?